# Python telegrambotapi

Tags: python, py-telegram-bot-api

When I click on the button that the function sends, nothing happens, but the callback should be processed, this can generally be that the handler does not work on more than one callback?

```py
import telebot 
from telebot import types 

bot = telebot.TeleBot('MyToken')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['button'])
def button(message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
    item = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Как дела?', callback_data='question_1')
    item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Пока', callback_data='goodbye')
    markup.add(item, item2)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет!', reply_markup=markup)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call:True)
async def callback(call):
    if call.message:
        if call.data == 'question_1':
            await bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.id, text= 'Дела отлично!')
        elif call.data == 'goodbye':
            await bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.id, text= 'Пока друг')

bot.polling()
```

I tried to update the version of pip and `pyTelegramBotAPI`, but this did not fix the problem. I also tried to change the callback conditions by using "... `callback_data=f"programs.{len(programs)}`" and `@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call:call.data.startswith("program."))`, but that didn't work. The bot doesn't respond when a button is pushed.

I have looked through the official posts about this issue, but I have not been able to find a solution. I would appreciate it if someone could check this code for themselves and provide feedback.

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem? else please specify

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, Telebot isnt async and doesnt support await statements. I edited your code and this should work as intended:

```
import telebot 
from telebot import types 

bot = telebot.TeleBot('MyToken')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['button'])
def button(message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
    item = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Как дела?', callback_data='question_1')
    item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Пока', callback_data='goodbye')
    markup.add(item, item2)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет!', reply_markup=markup)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback(call):
    if call.message:
        if call.data == 'question_1':
            bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.id, text='Дела отлично!')
        elif call.data == 'goodbye':
            bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.id, text='Пока друг')

bot.polling()
```

**EDIT WITH MY TEST:**
[image: My Test with the code i pasted here]

- write /button
- menu appears
- both buttons returns whats intended

Comment: thanks, I didn’t see it when I copied the code, but it didn’t solve the problem, when you click on the buttons, the bot also doesn’t react

Comment: hi ZONDER, i edited my test results in to the post for u to see how it works.

Comment: Emm.. it does not return callback, i tried it on my laptop too, and I am sure that the problem is in the code itself, but I don’t understand why after I click on the button, the bot doesn’t send me a message, and it feels like it doesn’t process it at all. even if I try to just print(call.data) - nothing happens

Comment: hmm i see. but is whats happening in my picture what you want to happen?
EDIT: You could try add print statements inside the def callback(call): function. just before the if call.message, add print(call), just to see if the bot receives a signal.